# Specifying a date range in a Symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, date-range

In my Symfony2 application there is an entity called 'Appointment'. This entity has a field/property called "date". It has a format like: '2012-12-24'.

I have created a form called AppointmentType, to be able to search for appointments based on their properties. The form is used in AppointmentController, and rendered to appointment.html.twig.

So far so good. I can search appointments based on all fields. I can for instance search on a specific date (that is, on an exact match).

However, I would like to be able to search for appointments given a date range (using a start and end date). The question would be: "Give me all appointments between this and that date." I've tried many things but can't figure it out in Symfony2.

Some random thoughts here:

- Should I create two extra fields in the Appointment entity beside
  "date", call them "startdate" and "enddate", not link them to the
  MySql table but only use them for search?
- Should I do something in the form, creating two date fields linked to the same date property of the entity (seems to cause violation)?
- Should I not use a Symfony2 form for this, but do it the old fashion way (manually write and process the form)? This works at the moment but it is far from elegant in a Symfony2 environment.

Any help is welcome. Especially a (complete) working code example would be awesome, so I can study it.

Comment: Take a look at tip in section [Creating form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) – there's mention about `property_path` option

Comment: I think you're right, jkucharovic! This must be it. Now I can specify two date properties in my form, while not linking them to the object. In my controller I use those two dates to specify a range to query for, as demonstrated by Lee Davis below. Thanks so much!

Comment: Simpler solution would be [Callback validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAppointmentsByDate($startDate, $endDate)
{
   $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a FROM Appointment a WHERE a.date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2');
   $query->setParameter(1, $startDate);
   $query->setParameter(2, $endDate);
   return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lee Davis. But what do you do with your form? If you want your form to display two widgets, one for start date and one for end date, while the entity only holds one date field, how do you achieve this? Once I have the dates, I can query as you demonstrated. But how to generate the form? Cheers, Paul